# RAS server in linux with analog modem

Tags: linux, modem, point-to-point-protocol

i known that the analog modem is a old technology, but in my enviroment i need it.
I have a server connected to a network 192.168.0.0/24 and all the internet is routed throw 192.168.0.254 and in the 192.168.0.3 i was deploy a RAS server with an analog modem connected to ttyS0 (COM 1). I was configurated a mgetty with pppd and from my home i dial to the modem for the analog line and connect well ( 33 kbps ;) ).

The problem is that (in the client, my laptop) in Linux when the connection has 2:30 mins elapsed the modem hangup with error code 15, that the explanation is that the ppp process dont recieve a reply from the server, but in Windows the connection don't hangup.

The main problem is that when i connect, i make 'ping 8.8.8.8' and works!!! but if i intent connect with a browser to www.google.com don't work, even i test connect with ssh with my server (without firewall), try and try, but never connect. Using wireshark i see that the packet is send but not return a response from the server.

In Windows I see that the connection has many errors in the input way. My configuration files are this

```
//----------------- [mgetty/mgetty.config]
debug 4 
speed 115200
issue-file /etc/issue.mgetty
//-------------------------------------

//----------------- [mgetty/login.config]
/AutoPPP/ -     a_ppp   /usr/sbin/pppd file /etc/ppp/options
*       -       -       /bin/login @
//-------------------------------------

//----------------- [ppp/options]
-detach
asyncmap 0
modem
crtscts
proxyarp                                                     
lock
require-pap
refuse-chap                   
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
usepeerdns
noauth
logfile /var/log/rasaccess.log
//-------------------------------------

//----------------- [ppp/options.ttyS0]
192.168.0.101:192.168.0.100           #serverAddress:clientAdress
noauth
debug
//-------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is the problem you are experiencing is connection drops or not being able to access DNS names from a computer connected through the modem?

Comment: I experiencing packets drop, but the ping works well, but any other connection nop. To access DNS names i need tcp or udp connection to 53, but only ping works.... if i ping 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 works well, the problem is stablish the connection with a server... directly, if i try connect direct with IP, then the connection wait forever